# ASP.NET - How to retrive a variable from a Sub with VB?

Tags: asp.net, global-variables, runatserver

I am using a `runat` command within a Public Sub in an .aspx page as follows:

```
<% Dim hasLabel %>
<script runat="server">
    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
            Dim fileExt As String
            fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)
            If (fileExt = ".docx" OR fileExt = ".doc") Then
                Try
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs("path_to_file" & _
                       FileUpload1.FileName)
                    Label1.Text = "<div class='centertext'>Statement Successfully Received, Thank You!<br /><br />File name: " & _
                       FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
                       "File Size: " & _
                       FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb</div>"
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
                End Try
            Else
                Label1.Text = "Only Word Document files allowed (.doc, .docx)."
            End If
        Else
            Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
        End If
        hasLabel = Label1.Text
    End Sub
</script>
```

Later on down the page, I'd like to be able to check `hasLabel` for content and if it's not empty, than just output this on the page, else, output the form again, something like this:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<% If hasLabel <> "" Than %>
    <div class="centertext"><%= hasLabel %></div>
<% Else %>
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" class="file" /><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload File" />&nbsp;<br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" class="mission_gothic_reg smalltext"></asp:Label>
        </div>
<% End If %>
</form>
</body>
```

How can I accomplish this?  Right now, I get an error that says:  `Name 'hasLabel' is not declared`

Basically, what I am trying to have happen, is... don't show the file upload button if a file has already been submitted.  Ofcourse, I will most likely need to change this for only doing this when it has been successfully uploaded and the file type is correct.  But I can't even find out a simple solution for knowing if it has been uploaded properly or not within the actual ASP page.  Yeah, I can output text that manipulates the  tag, but how to know if the label tag has anything in it to begin with, in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the Visible property to FALSE:

```
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
            Dim fileExt As String
            fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)
            If (fileExt = ".docx" OR fileExt = ".doc") Then
                Try
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs("FULL Upload File Path\" & _
                       FileUpload1.FileName)
                    Label1.Text = "<div class='mission_gothic_reg success'>Statement Successfully Received, Thank You!<br />File name: " & _
                       FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
                       "File Size: " & _
                       FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb</div>"
                       Button1.Visible = FALSE
                       FileUpload1.Visible = FALSE
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Label1.Text = "<div class='mission_gothic_reg fail'>ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString() & "</div>"
                End Try
            Else
                Label1.Text = "<div class='mission_gothic_reg fail'>Only Word Document files allowed (.doc, .docx).</div>"
            End If
        Else
            Label1.Text = "<div class='mission_gothic_reg fail'>You have not specified a file.</div>"
        End If
    End Sub
</script>
```

Maybe this will help someone else.